# Why is my number not showing up in scientific notation inside a 'S'-type column?

Tags: tables, siunitx, booktabs

I am using the following code to create a table that contains some regression results:

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{report}

    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{siunitx}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}[!htbp]
    \begin{tabular}{
            l
            S[table-format=2.3, table-number-alignment=center]
            S[table-format=2.3, table-number-alignment=center]
            S[table-format=2.3, table-number-alignment=center]
            S[table-format=1.3, table-number-alignment=center]
        }
        \toprule
        \textbf{Variable} & {\textbf{Coeficiente}} & {\textbf{Error estándar}} & {\textbf{Valor t}} & {\textbf{Valor p}} \\
        \midrule
        Intersección & 20,1176 & 2,6970 & 7,459 & 8.21e-08\\
        gov & -0,5814 & 0,1421 & -4,092 & 0.0004\\
        emp\textunderscore pro & -0,9289 &  0,2563 & -3,624 & 0,0013\\
        \midrule
        Error estándar residual & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$1,839$}\\
        Coeficiente de determinación $R^2$ & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$0,6068$} \\
        Coeficiente de determinación ajustado & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$0,5753$} \\
        Estadística F de Snedecor & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$19,29$} \\
        Valor p & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$8.576e-06$} \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\centering
\caption{Modelo de crecimiento del PIB, 2007}
\label{tab:regression_results}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

For some reason, the output looks like this:

[image: output]

As you can see, the first value in the last column is missing the scientific notation format that was included in the script. Any tips as to how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the first value in the last column is missing the scientific notation format that was included in the script.

This is happening because you've defined the last column to be formatted as `S[table-format=1.3]`: you have *not* set aside any space for the scientific-exponent term. I think that what you need is `S[table-format=1.3e-1]`. The `e-1` particle informs the `siunitx` package that enough space has to be set aside to show something like `10^{-5}`.

Aside: I think it's easier to write `emp\_pro` rather than `emp\textunderscore pro`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,spanish]{report}
\usepackage{geometry} % set page size parameters as needed
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
    
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{S[table-format=#1,
                       tight-spacing,
                       exponent-product=\cdot,
                      ]}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\begin{tabular}{@{} l C{2.4} C{1.4} C{-1.3} C{1.2e-1} @{}}
    \toprule
    Variable & {Coef.} & {Error} & {Valor $t$} & {Valor $p$} \\
             & & {estándar} \\
    \midrule
    Intersección  & 20,1176 & 2,6970 &  7,459 & 8.21e-08\\
    gov           & -0,5814 & 0,1421 & -4,092 & 0.0004  \\
    emp\_pro      & -0,9289 & 0,2563 & -3,624 & 0,0013  \\
    \midrule
    Error estándar residual              & \multicolumn{3}{C{2.3e-1}}{1,839}\\
    Coeficiente de determinación $R^2$   & \multicolumn{3}{C{2.3e-1}}{0,6068}\\
    Coeficiente de determinación ajustado& \multicolumn{3}{C{2.3e-1}}{0,5753}\\
    Estadística $F$ de Snedecor          & \multicolumn{3}{C{2.3e-1}}{19,29}\\
    Valor $p$                            & \multicolumn{3}{C{2.3e-1}}{8.576e-6}\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\centering
\caption{Modelo de crecimiento del PIB, 2007}
\label{tab:regression_results}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you for the help with the siunitx package format, and yes, it is a lot easier to use \_; I have always used \%, I am not sure how it's taking me this long to find out about this. Cheers!